# Gunicorn failed to start as it fails to identify the version of a package

Tags: python, flask, jira, gunicorn

While gunicorn is attempting to run flask server, the following error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pbr/version.py", line 442, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    provider = pkg_resources.get_provider(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 344, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 892, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jira' distribution was not found and is required by the application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    from customer_account_automation.app import app as application
  File "/root/flask/customer_account_automation/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jira import JIRA
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    _v = VersionInfo('jira').semantic_version()
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pbr/version.py", line 462, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pbr/version.py", line 449, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 876, in get_version
    name=package_name))
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name jira was given, but was not able to be found.
```

Here you find jira module installed

```
(customer) root@jsd:~/flask# pip freeze --all
...
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
jira==2.0.0
....
```

The weird thing is that when running `flask run` instead, it works and never complains, so I am thinking there is a problem with gunicorn.

The command I run gunicorn with is:

```
gunicorn --bind jsd.tv:5000 wsgi:customer_account_automation/app --pythonpath /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/customer-account-automation-gLS21FFx/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?